# IntegrityError on model with two m2m fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql, many-to-many, django-orm

This is what my model looks like:

```
class Interaction(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Interaction_Type)
    comments = models.TextField()
    related_clients = models.ManyToManyField(Client, related_name="interactions", blank=True)
    related_staff = models.ManyToManyField(Staff, related_name="interactions", blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When I try to save an instance of this model, I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "interactions_interaction_related_clients" violates foreign key constraint "interact_interaction_id_4927567c_fk_interactions_interaction_id"
DETAIL:  Key (interaction_id)=(85eb4cff-1be8-45f7-af40-459418ec6364) is not present in table "interactions_interaction".
```

It feels like that Django is trying to write to the pivot tables before writing to the main Interaction, Staff and Client tables.

Is there any remedy to this?

Comment: Can u show Client model too?

Comment: Client model is literally just like 200 CharFields

Comment: @user2288983 Try **null=True** also before migrations and migrate and if issue persists, delete those tables and reapply migrations, migrate after *null=True**.

Comment: null=True has no effect on ManyToMany fields.

Comment: Also this table is empty, it has just been freshly migrated